# Go - Casting a pointer to slice of struct to an slice of an interface

Tags: go, pointers

I have cut down some production GoLang code, to create the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var aData []AlphaStruct
    var bData []BetaStruct

    readData(&aData)
    readData(&bData)

    // Do other stuff with the loaded structures.
}

func readData(structSlicePointer any) {
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(
        "["+
            "{\"name\": \"John Smith\"},"+
            "{\"name\": \"Jane Doe\"}"+
            "]"),
        structSlicePointer)

    var initializers []Initializer

    // At this point I want to do:
    // initializers = structSlicePointer
    // However I can't find any type declarations or casts that will work with the rest of the code.

    for _, initializer := range initializers {
        initializer.Initialize()
    }
}

type Initializer interface {
    Initialize()
}

type AlphaStruct struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type BetaStruct struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func (es *AlphaStruct) Initialize() {
    fmt.Printf("In Alpha: %s\n", es.Name)
}

func (es *BetaStruct) Initialize() {
    fmt.Printf("In Beta: %s\n", es.Name)
}
```

I have a number of structures that all implement the same interface.

The idea is that after deserializing them (from JSON) I want to call a method on each loaded object in order to complete the objects initialization. Some of the JSON files have a top level array - i.e. once deserialized they are a list/slices of structures.

However I have been unable to find any combination of declarations that will allow me to both:

- Perform the `json.Unmarshal()`
- Iterate through each of the loaded structures and invoke the method.

Clearly I could just split this into two functions (loadData and initializeData) to perform the two functions.

Is there any way to restructure this to get it to work as a single method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the method as generic, which takes in a slice with member structs that implement the `Initializer` interface.

To do so you can declare you method like so:

```
func readData[T Initializer](structSlicePointer *[]T) {
    json.Unmarshal(
        []byte("[{\"name\": \"John Smith\"},{\"name\": \"Jane Doe\"}]"),
        structSlicePointer,
    )
    for _, initializer := range *structSlicePointer {
        initializer.Initialize()
    }
}
```

Note that this will require you to declare your slice values as pointers to work with pointer receiver methods on the structs (e.g. `[]*AlphaStruct` vs `[]AlphaStruct`):

```
func main() {
    var aData []*AlphaStruct
    var bData []*BetaStruct

    readData(&aData)
    readData(&bData)
}
```

Output:

```
In Alpha: John Smith
In Alpha: Jane Doe
In Beta: John Smith
In Beta: Jane Doe
```